# JQuery Ajax limiting deep recursion "too much recursion"

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, ajax, recursion

The idea is that I send lots of synchronous requests to an **API** to create a **JSON** that I will need later to do some clusterizations. This **API** gives me information about articles, review etc. from a site (scopus.com). First I send a request based on a query from which I get a **JSON** which contains information about some articles. These articles are cited by other articles. I have to get information about these ones too so I need recursion. The problem is that I get an error because of "too much recursion". It seems that the error appears when the recursion is over and the program has to go back to the "root"/the first call. So the program will look like a very deep tree.

Pure Javascript does have this limitation too? What can I do?

Also I have to do **SYNCHRONOUS** requests otherwise the **JSON** I will get will be a mess.

**EDIT:**

I tested the script on queries that need a small recursion such as a tree with 4-5 levels.

```
var result = '{"entry":[ ';

function query(){
var results = getNumberResults();
if(results>0)
{
    var pages = Math.ceil(results/25);
    var i;
    for(i=0; i<pages; i++){
        $.when($.ajax({
          url: url,
          type: "GET",
          async: false,
          headers: {'Accept':'application/json'},
          success: function(data){
            $.each( data['search-results']['entry'], function( i, item ) {
                get info from json and save it in my variable

                if(data['search-results']['entry'][i]['citedby-count'] > 0)
                    getCitedBy(data['search-results']['entry'][i]['eid']);
                else{
                    result += '"children-id":[]},';
                }
            });
          }
        }));
    }
}
result = result.slice(0,-1);
result += "]}";
}

function getCitedBy(eid){
var results = getCitedByNumberResults(eid);
if(results>0)
{
    var pages = Math.ceil(results/25);
    var i;
    for(i=0; i<pages; i++){
        $.when($.ajax({
          url: url,
          type: "GET",
          async: false,
          headers: {'Accept':'application/json'},
          success: function(data){
            $.each( data['search-results']['entry'], function( i, item ) {
                get info from json and save it in my variable

                if(data['search-results']['entry'][i]['citedby-count'] > 0)
                    getCitedBy(data['search-results']['entry'][i]['eid']);
                else{
                    result += '"children-id":[]},';
                }
            });
          }
        }));
    }
}
}

function getNumberResults(){
var innerResult;
$.ajax({
  url: url,
  type: "GET",
  async: false,
  headers: {'Accept':'application/json'},
  success: function(output){
    innerResult = output['search-results']['opensearch:totalResults'];
  },
  error: function (xhr, ajaxOptions, thrownError) {
    innerResult = 0;
  }
});
return innerResult;
}

function getCitedByNumberResults(eid){
var innerResult;
$.ajax({
  url: url,
  type: "GET",
  async: false,
  headers: {'Accept':'application/json'},
  success: function(output){
    innerResult = output['search-results']['opensearch:totalResults'];
  },
  error: function (xhr, ajaxOptions, thrownError) {
    innerResult = 0;
  }
});
return innerResult;
}
```

Comment: show the code you are using

Comment: Have you thought of articles referencing each other, and how to deal with that? Or deeper cycles, like article A references B, that references C, that references A? If not, you'll certainly get into this type of errors.

Comment: I thought about that but newer articles reference older articles so it doesn't seem possible. For example an article published in 2005 is cited by one published in 2012. So it's not possible the other way.

Comment: @Andrew I was just thinking since you go to do a deep search. What if you do something like google does. First you show most relevant/recent. Then after x seconds you go for lvl 2 then for lvl as they scroll or click a button. If you have something like show older posts? Or show related post then u have the list can you can go from the list you already have. As you said instead of going in recursion I think  another good way would have been to get all of them at once and then just short through them

Comment: @trincot it seems it's possible; I will try to fix it and I will give a response here

Comment: Note also that `getCitedByNumberResults` does not use its `eid` argument. It has exactly the same code as `getNumberResults`, and so will return the same. I would expect the `eid` would need to be passed as data to the Ajax call.

Comment: that function is ok, these 2 functions differ in the URL; that's why they have the same code in the sample I posted. EID is used in URL

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was as trincot mentioned and I also thought so was that 2 or more articles are referencing each other making an infinite cycle. I fixed it by searching my string variable for the unique identifier. So if in my variable already exists and article with that identifier I will skip recursion for the current article.

So I tested my script again for relative short queries (few hundreds of articles returned) because there are queries with huge outputs (millions of articles). When I will search for big queries I could come upon string size limitations(browser specific) or even “too much recursion”. If so I will let you know.

**Advice:** if “too much recursion” error occurs in your ajax request search first for an infinite cycle because this is the most probable cause.